# countdown timer on list giving the same timer results for each list item rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, countdown

Im trying to create a countdown timer and for some reason the class inst making each of these countdowns unique. All of my countdowns are the same eventhough they all are different due_dates.

- in my console.log(reservation.duedate) i get different due_dates which is correct and what it is suppose to be.
- the countdown is using the first result of due_date for each of the lists in the countdown function in js. This is not correct; each countdown must be separate for each list item.

[image: what it looks like]

This is in your_essays method in reservations_controller:

```rails
@reservations_pending = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", false).where("completed = ?", false).where("due_date >= ?", DateTime.now).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page_pending]).per_page(3)
```

your_essays.html.erb:

```html
<div id="content-load-more-pending">
 <%= render 'your_essays_pending', reservations_pending: @reservations_pending %>
</div>
```

This is the partial within your_essays.html.erb called _your_essays_completed.html.erb

```html
<% reservations_pending.each do |reservation| %>

<div style="color:blue;" class="countdown-class"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".countdown-class")
.countdown("<%= reservation.due_date %>", function(event) {
$(this).text(
event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
);
});

console.log("<%= reservation.due_date %>");
</script> 

<% end %>
```

here is console.log(event) and console.log("<%= reservation.due_date %>");
[image]

Comment: What event is actually being passed to the javascript function? (can you console.log that?)

Comment: There is an error in your implementation. You are update THE ENTIRE CLASS WITH THE CURRENT DATA in every row... That's not how you should do it.

Comment: I added the console.log(event) picture to the question to show what i see in my console. the first date of the event is different then all the ones after it all show the same date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you go through the loop, you're resetting every instance of `.countdown-class` to the new due date. That should explain why they're all taking on the value of the last one.

There's a couple of ways to fix this. You could use the `id` of each reservation and add it to the class name, for example. This gives you uniques classes, and allows each successive change to not affect previous ones.

You could also streamline the code by doing something like:

```
<% reservations_pending.each do |reservation| %>
  <div style="color:blue;" class="countdown-class" data-due-date="<%= reservation.due_date %>"></div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".countdown-class").each(function() {
    $(this).countdown($(this).data("due-date"), function(event) {
      $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

By "storing" the due date inside a data attribute on the div itself, you're able to eliminate the repetition of the JS code.

Edit: here's a working example https://jsfiddle.net/3j368s46/

Comment: in my console im getting an error and its not showing up the error seems to be caught in the js file that i copy pasted into my assets/javascripts. The Error is: `throw new Error("Couldn't cast " + dateString + " to a date object.");` in a method called: `function parseDateString(dateString) {`.  Im using: `The Final Countdown for jQuery v2.2.0 (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)`

Comment: The main error says: `Uncaught Error: Couldn't cast 'undefined' to a date object.`

Comment: That's what happens when I write code without testing it :-)  Have amended the answer now, and there's a fiddle to show it in action.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! I didn't just learn about the countdown from you but the fiddle too I didnt think about how to test data without db. thank you very much!! ^^

Comment: Just curious, is .countdown in your fiddle a native js function?  Is there a 'countup' version by any chance?

Comment: @fatfrog: it's using this plugin (which is linked in the resources on the fiddle): http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/